# Can't send jwtToken from react client to node/express backend with axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, jwt

I am about to learn full stack development with react, node and postgresql and facing a jwttoken authorization issue. I need your support.

Whenever I try to send my token from react to my backend API with axios I get following error message.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

If I use postman or remove the authorization it works perfectly fine.

After some research I applied cors as middleware but still it doesn't work.

Further code:

**server side**

authorization.js

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    console.log("TEST");
    console.log(req.header("token"));

    // Get token from header
    const token = req.header("token"); 

    // Check if not token
    if (!token) {
      return res.status(403).json("Authorization denied");
    }

    const payload = jwt.verify(token, process.env.jwtSecret);

    req.user = payload.user;

    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(403).json("Token is not valid");
  }
};
```

server.js

```
import express from "express";
const morgan = require("morgan");
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
dotenv.config();

const app = express();

// bring in routes
import hotelRoutes from "./routes/hotel";

// route middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api/hotel", hotelRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`A node Js API is listening to port: ${port}`)
);
```

hotel.js // routes

```
const express = require("express");
const { createhotel } = require("../controllers/hotel");
const { createhotelValidator } = require("../validator");
const authorization = require("../middleware/authorization");

const router = express.Router();
router.post("/", createhotelValidator, authorization, createhotel);

module.exports = router;
```

**client side**

hotel.js

```
import axios from "axios";

export const createhotel = async (token, data) => {
  await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/hotel`, data, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67556664/2822041

Comment: try header name "Authorization", not "token"... `const token = req.header("token"); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `token` to `Authorization` in your authorization.js file

```
console.log(req.header("Authorization"));

// Get token from header
const token = req.header("Authorization");
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. But I did have to remove "Bearer" prefix from my client side hotel.js posted in my initial post. What is "Bearer" and why do I need it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can split string with `Bearer `